# Some part of the cloth can't be sewed together

Tags: cloth-simulation

The shoulder part of the vest can't be sewed together, and the sewing line in the body seems to be not tight enough. I've tried to tune the size and other numbers, but it didn't work. Where does it go wrong? Thanks ahead!
[image]

[image]

This is the file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EB9nuuoJOHKWz6a27SW1I0yktLlQjfV-/view?usp=sharing